# Add more than 16 columns to clustered index

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way by which i can add more than 16 columns in clustered index.

Comment: 16 columns in a clustered index seems excessive. Maybe you should ask the question you really want the answer to?

Answer (score 7):

As of SQLserver 2008 , [no](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx). However , I suspect the bottleneck is somewhere else if you require a clustered index on more than 16 columns.

Answer (score 2):

No.  further, you are limited to a total of 900 bytes of data for the combined key size.

Quoting from the [Create Index reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783(SQL.90).aspx) page.

> Up to 16 columns can be combined into
>   a single composite index key. All the
>   columns in a composite index key must
>   be in the same table or view. The
>   maximum allowable size of the combined
>   index values is 900 bytes. For more
>   information about variable type
>   columns in composite indexes, see the
>   Remarks section.

Answer (score 2):

The 16 columns maximum in a clustered index can only by overcome by pure and total madness.  The kind where you are locked away from a computer forever, never allowed to attempt things like this.

Therefore, it is not possible.

Comment: I can understand why you were downvoted, but also understand your sentiment you should re word in a less offensive way

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted this isn't possible, or even desirable. Clustered indexes are not a good choice for wide keys [because](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190639.aspx):

> the key values from the clustered
>   index are used by all non-clustered
>   indexes as lookup keys. Any
>   non-clustered indexes defined on the
>   same table will be significantly
>   larger because the non-clustered index
>   entries contain the clustering key and
>   also the key columns defined for that
>   non-clustered index.

If you're happy with non-clustered indexes, then as of SQL Server 2005 and above you can use [Included Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx) to overcome the 900 byte, 16 column limits.

Answer (score 1):

No, 16 is the limit.

But you can combine the keys into one hash value. this should raise the speed. 
ofcurse the hash values should be indexed.