# Code First view number of keys

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I am trying to use Code First and Database Migration in MVC 5 project.  In one of the views I have 20 keys

```
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 19)]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string UseOftools { get; set; }
```

I get this error:

```
`the index '' on table "xxx"  has 20 columns in the key list. The maximum limit for index key column list is 16`.
```

I would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: I did that, it worked however the views were placed in tables.  I have to figure out how to generate views using Code First, or mix regular entity model to import views with code first.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677103/add-more-than-16-columns-to-clustered-index

Comment: Thank you, I guess it does not work